# keras model prediction only one and zero instead of probability

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

This is my model and data generator, when I predicted I got array([0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]  instead of probability. I think it should be a probability.

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add ...
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(num_class))
model.add(keras.layers.Softmax())

sgd_opt = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
cce_loss = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy

model.compile(optimizer=sgd_opt, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
train_data_dir,
target_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
batch_size=batch_size,
class_mode='sparse') 

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
test_data_dir, # same directory as training data
target_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
batch_size=batch_size,
class_mode='sparse')
```

Comment: 0 and 1 are valid probabilities, I am not sure what you mean "instead of probability".

Comment: I think it should be [0.7, 0.3, 0.1, ...] like this

Comment: The model decides that, not you, it is not a programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your model literally remembered labels for samples.
Validating on training data is bad practice. Try to split datasets:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
  validation_split=0.2
)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    subset='training',
    class_mode='sparse'
) 
validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    subset='validation',
    class_mode='sparse')
```

Comment: You cannot claim overfitting without looking at training and validation/test loss values.

Comment: Thank you very much ^^